# $index is not working in ng-if in the dir-paginate division

Tags: angularjs, indexing, angularjs-directive, angular-ng-if

```
<div dir-paginate="metric in currentDashboard.metrics | itemsPerPage: 10: 'metricsPages'" class="metric-holder ss-active-child:hidden" pagination-id="metricsPages" data-ng-if="$index > 0">
```

This how I used $index in my code. The div stopped rendering completely even though the length of the metrics array is not 0.

And $index is working for the children of this div.

Can anyone help me out.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: From your code, it looks like you only want to display the first element of the array. Is that true?

Comment: put the `ng-if` inside the `ng-repeat`, like in another div.

Comment: Do you mean checking the metrics array length in ng-if? Something like this <div ng-repeat="thumb in photos" ng-if="photos.length > 1"></div>

Comment: You actually answered your question on your own , "And $index is working for the children of this div. " this is the expected behaviour of $index   .

Comment: I wanted to render the div when the for all the elements in the array except the first one. Tarun Dugar